# TSQL Query check for each user ID to have at least 4 distinct status rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to check that a specific user ID has all 4 separate status types in separate rows. Referencing the table below, the check should pass for User 1 & 2, but not 3 & 4.

[image]

Is there a way to do this with one select statement? Or will I have to use four separate checks? I tried the following, however this would fail if a user had 4 status's that were of any type regardless if they were distinct types. **Also the Type_Status columns are BIT not INT.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.User_Status AS CS
WHERE User_ID = @User_ID
AND
(
  Type_1_Status = 1 OR
  Type_2_Status = 1 OR
  Type_3_Status = 1 OR
  Type_4_Status = 1
)
```

Comment: Use `having` clause with `count(status)` function.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Try to read Books Online about the elements I mentioned, and write your own query. If your query does not work, update your question with what you tried.

Comment: I'm not grouping by anything and using a having clause without an grouping functions just like a where clause? Are you suggesting I group by something?

Comment: You should read up on normalization. This table violates 1NF because of repeating groups. You should have the status value in another table. Consider what happens when you need to add status 5, you will have to change your table and every single query that touches this table. UGH!!!

Comment: @Goblaz kindly check my solution  after editing it and run the code and you will get what you are asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Table where User_ID in
(  select User_ID from table 
   group by User_ID 
   having SUM(CAST(Type_1_Status as INT)) > 0 and 
   SUM(CAST(Type_2_Status as INT)) > 0 and
   SUM(CAST(Type_3_Status as INT)) > 0 and
   SUM(CAST(Type_4_Status as INT)) > 0  )
```

Comment: What does the outer nested query achieve that the inner query does not?

Comment: Attempted this however the status_type columns are bits and I receive "Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator." error.

Comment: Use cast operator
CAST(Type_1_Status as tinyint)

Comment: Added cast. Please edit your OP to include that the status is BIT for other people @Goblaz

Comment: That seems unnecessary for the task I'm trying to complete. Casting a column just to check if a user has distinct status's? There has to be another way without casting BITs as INTs. This is for a stored procedure.

Comment: There's 100 ways @Goblaz. You can do it with an extensive case statement too... it's more code. There are plenty of ways to achieve this.

Comment: your query will work for duplicated entries? what if the records should appear once? still valid?

Comment: If you don't want to use cast you can use COUNT(NULLIF(Type_1_Status,0)) instead of SUM(CAST(Type_1_Status as int))

Comment: @HadiHassan you are making assumptions which are endless

Answer (score 0):

You can group by user_id and sum type_status if sums in all types is grather then 0 
then condition is fulfilled

```
SELECT USER_ID, CAST(IIF(SUM(Type_1_Status) > 0 and SUM(Type_2_Status) > 0 and SUM(Type_3_Status) > 0 and SUM(Type_4_Status) > 0, 1, 0) as bit) as Pass
FROM tab
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Comment: This will still return all rows.

Comment: No, it will return only one row for each user

Comment: Yes. But for all users, whether they pass the check or fail.

Comment: In second column is bit value with 1 for pass the check and 0 for fail.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following

1. Convert the columns to rows with counting
2. Group on count  having count =4 and Status =1

This method will ensure that the Status was assigned once and will not show as result the duplicated records for example a user will 2 records with `Status_1_Type=1`

here a sample code

```
    declare @table table(UserId int,
                     Type_1_Status bit,                  
                     Type_2_Status bit,
                     Type_3_Status bit,
                     Type_4_Status bit)
insert into @table(UserId,Type_1_Status,Type_2_Status,Type_3_Status,Type_4_Status)
select 1,1,0,0,0
union 
select 1,0,1,0,0
union
select 1,0,0,1,0
union 
select 1,0,0,0,1
union all
select 2,0,0,0,1
union all
select 2,0,0,0,1
union all
select 2,0,0,0,1
union all
select 2,0,0,0,1

;with report as(
select UserId,'Status1' as Type,count(Type_1_Status) over(order by UserId) as Status
from @table
where Type_1_Status=1
union all
select UserId,'Status2' as Type,count(Type_2_Status) over(order by UserId)
from @table
where Type_2_Status=1
union all
select UserId,'Status3' as Type,count(Type_3_Status) over(order by UserId)
from @table
where Type_3_Status=1
union all
select UserId,'Status4' as Type,count(Type_4_Status) over(order by UserId)
from @table
where Type_4_Status=1)
select UserId,count(Status)
from  report
where Status=1
group by UserId
having count(Status) =4
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Why down voting  without discussion?